# Powershell script to get list of AD groups used from site collections in SharePoint 2010

Tags: active-directory, groups, powershell

I need to list all the AD groups used in all the site collection.
Can any one please help.

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://*******.com/

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$SPsite.RootWeb.Title 
    ##write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$SPsite.RootWeb.URL
    $SiteURL = $SPsite.RootWeb.URL
    $ADgroup=Get-SPUser -Web $SiteURL  | Where { $_.IsDomainGroup }
    foreach($group in $ADgroup)
    {
        write-host $group.DisplayName
        $Output += ($group.DisplayName)
        $users = new-object psobject
        $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Site Collection" -value $SPsite.RootWeb.Title
        $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Groups" -value $group.DisplayName
        $combinedusers += $users
    } 
    $combinedusers | export-csv "F:\group.csv" -notypeinformation
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below snippet

```
Get-SPUser -Web http://server/sites/yoursite | Where { $_.IsDomainGroup }
```

AD group is treated as a special user. So this can be find using the filter [`IsDomainGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.isdomaingroup(v=office.14).aspx)

**Update**

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://*******.com/

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$SPsite.RootWeb.Title 
    ##write-host -foregroundcolor green "Working on Site Collection: "$SPsite.RootWeb.URL
    $SiteURL = $SPsite.RootWeb.URL
    $ADgroup=Get-SPUser -Web $SiteURL -Limit ALL | Where { $_.IsDomainGroup }
    foreach($group in $ADgroup)
    {
        if($Output -notcontains $group.DisplayName)
        {
            write-host $group.DisplayName
            $Output += ($group.DisplayName)
            $users = new-object psobject
            $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Site Collection" -value $SPsite.RootWeb.Title
            $users | add-member noteproperty -name "Groups" -value $group.DisplayName
            $combinedusers += $users
        }
    } 
    $combinedusers | export-csv "F:\group.csv" -notypeinformation
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amal...it worked. I have one more requirement. 
Right now the code I have done lists all the groups from all the site collections. But I want single list of groups used within all the site collection.  I have added my code above. please suggest any changes. let me know if need is not clear.

Comment: What you mean by single list? You mean remove duplicates?

Comment: correct. I have added code above in my post.

Comment: @RajeevK I added an `if` statement to check if the group is already added or not.

Comment: Thanks Amal..I will check this.. will let you know in some time...:)

Comment: Hello Amal,
It worked by using "-unique"
$test = $combinedgroups | Select-Object -Property Groups -Unique

Thanks for your help...:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cycle one way or the other, by this I mean iterate either through AD groups or through SharePoint groups and compare the two.... I'm lazy and created a console application that explains how to do it. When I get the chance I will post PS code!

.cs code is checking against AD and looping SharePoint as I think you could have many AD groups and fewer SharePoint groups. This is up to you as you can use `site.RootWeb.EnsureUser()` to check against, but either way you're still going to have to call AD to get groups.

```
        try
        {
            //get the web application via url, only need the host header and port its using. Look in central admin at webapplication list to see what it's using. 
            SPWebApplication webapp = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://webapplicationUrl:80/"));
            //get all the site collections within the web application. Add it into SPSiteCollection for better speed , get it once for less calls and stored locally
            SPSiteCollection siteCol = webapp.Sites;
            //loop through each site colleciton
            foreach (SPSite site in siteCol)
            {
                //use try block to finish with the spsite object at the end so there is no memory leaks.
                try
                {
                    //get the whole group at the root level for the site collection, get it once for less calls and stored locally
                    SPGroupCollection groupCol = site.RootWeb.Groups;
                    //loop thorough each sharepoint group to check against.
                    foreach (SPGroup group in groupCol)
                    {
                        //change principal context to a domain account 
                        //  "mydomain.com" is the domain name the you are trying to access in active directory 
                        //  "wilma" is the account name that is a domain account that has access to active directory
                        //  "wilma's Password" this is where you put in the domain account password
                        var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "easyas.com", "wilma", "wilma's Password");
                        GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, group.Name);

                        //if null than it doesn't exist in AD! 
                        if (groupPrincipal != null)
                        {
                            //show message that it exists
                            Console.WriteLine("Group '" + group.Name + "' exists");
                        }
                        {
                            //show message that it doesn't exist
                            Console.WriteLine("Group '" + group.Name + "' does not exists in AD");
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    //when finished disposed of the spsite object
                    site.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error caught : " + a.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

The PS code (as I can't be arsed to write it as it's Friday). I found what I'm pretty much doing above; It's in no way complete and needs amending to get from webapplication rather than from one site collection. The majority of the work is there though so shouldn't be hard to figure out.

```
#--------------------------------------------------#
# modules
#--------------------------------------------------#
if(-not (Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
#--------------------------------------------------#
# main
#--------------------------------------------------#
# get spweb object
$SPWeb = Get-SPweb $(Get-SPUrl $Identity).Url
# get spsite object
$SPSite = $SPWeb.Site
# get root web object
$SPRootWeb = $SPSite.RootWeb
# get role definition by id
$SPRole = $SPWeb.RoleDefinitions | where{$_.Name -eq $Role -or $_.ID -eq $Role}
# get adgroup format domain\name
$ADGroup = "$((Get-ADDomain).Name)" + "`\" + $(Get-ADGroup $ADGroup).Name
# create a new role assignment object
$SPGroup = $SPRootWeb.EnsureUser($ADGroup)
# abort if group doesn't exist
if($SPGroup -eq $Null)
{
     throw "Group not found!"
}
else
{  
     group found so print to .csv or screen!
}
```

https://github.com/janikvonrotz/PowerShell-PowerUp/blob/master/functions/SharePoint/Set-SPADGroupPermission.ps1#L105

Comment: Thanks a lot...:) I am not much familiar with PS..so I will try this.. and will let you know :)